VLC and other media players does not start! While running through CLI I got segmentation fault error!
I am using Ubuntu 24.04 LTS version. I installed VLC through app store the stable one but the application does not run so i installed various realse of VLC like beta etc. Finally I installed the VLC (beta) through snap but that also not works i also tried another players like Grid player available in app store that also does not works!...
keerthi@tux:~$ vlc
[0000575064f23a00] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket
Fontconfig warning: FcPattern object weight does not accept value [0 205)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)```


I am using Ubuntu 24.04 LTS version. I installed various VLC stable version first through app store. And I also Installed beta and other versions too but nothing worked. So I decided to uninstall and install it through snap and this is the last command I executed.
"sudo snap install --channel="beta" vlc"

Also the title makes no sense all you talk about is vlc

Remove VLC snap, and install the apt package instead. It works for me in Kubuntu 24.04 without any issues.
Open a terminal and run the two commands one by one.
sudo snap remove vlc
sudo apt install vlc


Yes it works. Thank you so much!
